# Django using two Foreign Keys to the same model throws error despite using related_name

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to use two one-to-many links to the same model and getting the following error when running makemigrations:

```
<class 'actionlog.admin.ActionInstanceInline'>: (admin.E202) 'actionlog.Action' has more than one ForeignKey to 'actionlog.Audit'.
```

Searching shows this is a common problem resolved by using related name.  However, this doesn't fix the error for me.  Could someone show me what I'm missing?  The models are:

```
class Audit(models.Model):
    audit_ref = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    audit_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lead_auditor = models.ForeignKey('LeadAuditor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Action(models.Model):
    action_ref = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    audit_ref = models.ForeignKey('Audit', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lead_auditor = models.ForeignKey('Audit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lead_auditors')
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you also add ActionInstanceInline to your question, maybe the problem is in that object

Comment: I'm not consciously trying to create that object, I thought it was an artifact automatically created when setting up the models.  Possibly, therein lies the problem.

Comment: Ah, here it is:  class ActionInstanceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Action
    fields = ('action_ref', 'status', 'action')
    editable = False
    extra = 0

Comment: If your runserver starts, django does an setup, which also initiates all the objects for the admin. Thus if your have an error somewhere in the initialisation of the admin, there will be an error.

Comment: Ok, that's clearly where the problem is, nothing to do with foreignkey or related_name.  Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: The problem probably lies that your Inline doesn't know for which of the Audit FK's is your Inline for. Don't know the solution, but you can probably find it in the django docs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the following code

```
class Action(models.Model):
     action_ref = models.CharField(max_length=3)
     audit_ref = models.ForeignKey('Audit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="audit_ref_actions")
     lead_auditor = models.ForeignKey('Audit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lead_auditor_actions')
```